# How to estimate the power consumption for this servo system?

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to roughly estimate the power consumption of [this GVS112](https://www.thorlabs.com/_sd.cfm?fileName=20381-D02.pdf&partNumber=GVS112) galvo system.  The system is based on two galvanometer drivers (for X and Y movements) and is powered by [this GPS011](https://www.thorlabs.com/_sd.cfm?fileName=20378-D02.pdf&partNumber=GPS011) power supply as follows:

[image: ...]

The thing is, the PSU is rated for 175W and the manual says: "The drive electronics require a split rail DC supply in the range ±15V to ±18V. The cards do not require an accurately regulated supply as the boards themselves have their own regulators. The maximum current drawn by the driver cards will not exceed 1.2 A rms on each rail".

In my case what would be the total power consumption? (Also the supply's efficiency is not given).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell, since your links are dead. Even if they were live, you have not specified your galvo performance profile. Your quote provides a number of "the driver cards will not exceed 1.2 amps on each rail" Since the limit seems to apply to the total system, worst-case power is 1.2 amps a 36 volts, or about 43 watts. If the limit is actually 1.2 amps per card, then you would need about 86 watts. Divided, of course, by the efficiency of the PSU. It seems very unlikely that a 175 watt power supply will be inadequate. As a matter of fact, a linear PSU has a worst-case efficiency of about 0.5, so the nominal worst-case power consumption is 172 watts, which I'd guess is not a coincidence.

Comment: I see but where did you get the 36 volts?

Comment: For some reason periodically they change the links and here new ones for the system  https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/3d73c8cd387012c6-AE6F4491-E4BF-F82A-D0FACB7272403060/GVS112-Manual.pdf and PSU https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/3d73c8cd387012c6-AE6F4491-E4BF-F82A-D0FACB7272403060/GPS011-Manual.pdf